# Npm installation deprecated error while installing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

When I am trying to install `expo-cli` package, It stops and gives the message that

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated
```

[image: error image]

Your help will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: this is just a warning, not even an error.

Comment: Did you try install with yarn? Can't you install it even with this warning?

Comment: Yes. Even cant install with Yarn.

Comment: What does the command `npm config list` give? Check the value of `registry` there. See if there is some setting in proxy or something you do not want. Remove what you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an error, just a warning, so it can't stop installation progress and you can use current package.